# Is there any way to fetch ajax data as separate variable instead of full HTML?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch book rows by books' first letter with jquery `$.post` into my `<td> </td>` which is part of my table.

My table looks like :

```
<table id="myTable">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="page">pages</th>
      <th class="book_name">Book Name</th>
      <th class="author">Author</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="result_list">
  <!--Here is data which will come with ajax($.post) -->                 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Writing jquery code, I become successful but with `$("#result_list").html(data)` like this:

```
$.post( "/ajax.php", { book_first_letter: 'A'},
  function( data ) {
      $( "#result_list" ).html( data );
  }
);
```

But I dont want to fetch all data as HTML and insert into `<tbody>` . I want to fetch data from ajax.php as separate variable. For example; book_name,logo,pages,author. And I want to insert them into `<td> </td>`.

My ajax.php is like this:

```
 $letter= trim($_POST['book_first_letter']);    
 $query = $this->book_model->get_books_by_letter($letter);       
 foreach ($query as $book) { ?>

     <tr>
         <td> <?php echo $book->page; ?> </td>
         <td> <?php echo $book->name; ?> </td>
         <td> <?php echo $book->author; ?> </td>

     </tr>
   <?php  
}
?>
```

Is there any way to take each variable(i.e. $book->name) and insert it into `<td></td>` ?

Comment: return the data in some format then parse it out (XML, JSON, CSV, etc.)

Comment: Are you using MySQL with php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only can you, but you should.
Rather than having PHP return html as text, have it return a JSON object.

You're going to need to do a few things. 
First add a fourth argument to your $.post() call for a dataType of "json".

```
$.post( "/ajax.php", { book_first_letter: 'A'}, callback, "json" );
```

Then, its good form to have PHP send JSON headers for the result so before you send out any data in PHP use

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

And rather than echoing out the properties of your book model, just use json_encode()

```
$letter= trim($_POST['book_first_letter']);    
$books = $this->book_model->get_books_by_letter($letter);
echo json_encode( $books );
```

So the client now has the raw data and you can use js/jQuery to loop through the books and add it to your table.

```
function callback( books)
{
   var i = 0, len = books.length, html = "";

    for( ; i < len; ; )
    {
        html += "however you want to structure the data";
    }

    $( "#result_list" ).html( html );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just transform your data into JSON by using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
$letter= trim($_GET['book_first_letter']);    
$query = $this->book_model->get_books_by_letter($letter);    
echo json_encode( $query );
```

On the client side you then use [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and have a similar object in JavaScript as you had in PHP:

```
$.getJSON( "/ajax.php", { book_first_letter: 'A'},
  function( data ) {
      // data has the same properties as $query did in PHP
  }
);
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @MrCode `getJSON()` just does a GET request. So i changed the way to access the parameter in the PHP code from `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Here a GET request is probably the better choice, anyway, as GET requests here could be cached by the browser, whereas POST request will have to be executed each time.

The other option would be to leave the POST request in place, which would change the client side JS to

```
$.post( "/ajax.php", { book_first_letter: 'A'},
  function( data ) {
      // data has the same properties as $query did in PHP
  }
  , 'json'
);
```

Comment: Won't work because getJSON does a GET request. OP wants POST. You should change it to $.post and set the fourth argument to `json`, or do a fullhand `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON will be your best way to do this

And depending on what you are getting back into `$query`  it should be as easy as

```
echo json_encode($query)
```

Then you will have to process the data on the client-side javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is - use JSON. PHP has [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. Just create an json-like array from your data nad use `json_encode` to send them to client. 
On client side, use `$.post` with `dataType: json`.

Answer (score 0):

you can return your variables as JSON.

In your ajax.php:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

In your jquery AJAX call:

```
$.post('ajax.php', { book_first_letter: 'A'}, function(data) {
    console.log(data) //view the data returned in the console of firebug
},'json');
```

Comment: Won't work because getJSON does a GET request. OP wants POST. You should change it to $.post and set the fourth argument to `json`, or do a fullhand `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Json encode. It also seems to me like soon you might start considering [backbone & underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) stack for your ajax needs. It features templating on the client, which looks like one of things you could definitely use in that example